# What does 'Error: the object is already disposed' mean? - Microsoft Speech SDK For Javascript

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, dispose

I'm using Microsoft Speech SDK for Javascript to do text to speech on a website.

While my application works on MOST machines. I am noticing that on some machines and browsers, I only seem to be able to receive one message. If I then try to receive any subsequent messages, I then get the following error:

> Error: the object is already disposed

This seems to happen when trying to do the following in microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js

```
SpeechRecognizer.prototype.close = function () {
    Contracts_1.Contracts.throwIfDisposed(this.privDisposedSpeechRecognizer);
    this.dispose(true);
};
```

Is anyone able to give some guidance regarding what this means?

Answer (score 1):

It would help, if you posted more code.
But the error means, that the ***SpeechRecognizer*** object has already been disposed.

In case you're calling the *.close()* function twice on the object.

It would have been great if there was a function to check if it is already closed, before calling *close()* on it. I haven't found any.

But, yeah, your answer is that you're probably calling the *.close()* function more than once.